# Element in dropdown not clickable exception after search (C# Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium, click, dropdown

I am trying to build an automation framework for my project and I am stuck at the below mentioned problem. Could you please offer some advice?

I have a "sort of" dropdown which includes a search input for a list of Countries. I search for a particular text "United States". Two results are displayed. I want to click on the second one.

Initial dropdown:

[image: Initial Dropdown]

Dropdown after search:

[image: Dropdown after search]

HTML code for the result of the search:

```
<span class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 253.087px;">
<span class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown">
<input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" aria-controls="select2-txtCountry-results" aria-activedescendant="select2-txtCountry-result-swi0-UM"></span>
<span class="select2-results">
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="listbox" id="select2-txtCountry-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-txtCountry-result-swi0-UM" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-txtCountry-result-swi0-UM">United States Minor Is.</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-txtCountry-result-xg7o-US" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-txtCountry-result-xg7o-US">United States</li>
</ul>
</span>
</span>
```

This is how I make the selection:

```
       protected void WaitForElement(IWebElement element, int timeout = 2)
       {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(iWebDriver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout));
            wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
            wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
            wait.Until<bool>(driver =>
            {
                try
                {
                     return (element.Displayed && element.Enabled);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        protected IList<IWebElement> FindAll(By locator, int timeoutInSeconds = 5)
        {
            if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(iWebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
                return wait.Until(drv => (drv.FindElements(locator).Count > 0) ? drv.FindElements(locator) : null);
            }
            return iWebDriver.FindElements(locator);
        }
        
        protected int getNumberOfElementsFound(By by)
        {
            return FindAll(by).Count();
        }

        protected IWebElement getElementWithIndex(By by, int pos)
        {
            return FindAll(by).ElementAt(pos);

        }

        protected void DropDownValueSelection(By containerLocator, By searchInputLocator, By dropdownItemsLocator, String value)
        {
                Click(containerLocator);
                Type(searchInputLocator, value);
                int numberOfElementsFound = getNumberOfElementsFound(dropdownItemsLocator);
                for (int pos = 0; pos < numberOfElementsFound ; pos++)
                {
                    IWebElement element = getElementWithIndex(dropdownItemsLocator, pos);
                    Console.WriteLine("element in for {0}", element.Text.ToString());
                    if (element.Text.Equals(value))
                    {
                        WaitForElement(element);
                        element.Click();
                        break;
                    }
                }
}
```

And here are the locators I use:

```
By dropdownItems => By.XPath("//span//ul[@class='select2-results__options']/li");
By CountryInput => By.Id("select2-txtCountry-container");
By CountrySearchInput => By.ClassName("select2-search__field");
```

I am supposing that the problem might be with the span that is found above the "//ul//li" dropdown items.
I have tried searching for the values without entering text in the search input and it works, but it takes a lot of time because there are over 200 entries in the countries list.
I am receiving the following error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click
> intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (445, 715)

I have also checked that the element is displayed and enabled, the page is not reloaded, there are no other elements (loader etc) on top except the span.
Thank you for your input.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. I edited your question to include the screenshots, which is useful information. But please [edit] your question to include the HTML as code, not as an image.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the post and added the HTML code.

Comment: Can you add the source code for the `WaitForElement` method?

Comment: I have added the method at the beginning of the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to click something until it succeeds. I'm not sure why, but Selenium does not come with an overload of `WebDriverWait.Until(...)` that has a `void` return type. I end up creating an extension method for the WebDriverWait class to allow this:

```
public static class WebDriverWaitExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Waits until no exception is thrown.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wait"></param>
    /// <param name="callback">The callback executed until no exception is thrown.</param>
    public static void Until(this WebDriverWait wait, Action<IWebDriver> callback)
    {
        wait.Until(driver =>
        {
            try
            {
                callback(driver);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now just wait until the click succeeds:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

// Using == easier to read than element.Text.Equals(value)
if (element.Text == value)
{
    wait.Until(d => element.Click());

    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Greg  
I tried implementing the extension, but I get the following error:  


    Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'DefaultWait<IWebDriver>.Until<TResult>(Func<IWebDriver, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot format my comment. I used the stackoverflow tutorial, but the tags do not seem to work.

Comment: @MirelaM: Make sure the namespace of this extension method class is the root name space of your project, or you add a `using X;` directive at the top of your C# file, where you replace "X" with the namespace of this class.